# Resizing Mountain Lion AND Bootcamp partition

Tags: partitioning, boot-camp, osx-mountain-lion

I have recently bought a new disk for my macbook pro which runs mountain lion.

I have succesfully cloned the old drive to the new drive, but I wish to resize the partitions to take advantage of the additional space.

I have tried using Disk Manager to resize the partition, but it wont let me. I assume this is becuase of the BootCamp partition being in the way. I have also tried diskutil from the console with the same issue.

I have also tried resizing the bootcamp partition whilst it was loaded and that worked fine, but Mountain Lion did not recognise these changes and still showed unallocated space in Disk Manager when in reality this had been allocated to windows.

What I want to do is resize the Mountain Lion partition (HFS+) and the Bootcamp partition (NTFS) to use all of the disk space.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I deleted the BootCamp partition, resized the Mountain Lion partition, then reinstalled Windows on a newly created Bootcamp partition.

Restoring an image to the new bootcamp partition caused BCD errors in Windows and no amount of fiddling with it in Windows Recovery Console would fix it

Answer (score 0):

Try [Gnome Partition Editor](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/).

It can perform actions with partitions such as:

create or delete
resize or move
check
label
set new UUID
copy and paste

Manipulate file systems such as:

btrfs
ext2 / ext3 / ext4
fat16 / fat32
hfs / hfs+
linux-swap
nilfs2
ntfs
reiserfs / reiser4
ufs
xfs
And many more features

Comment: This says that it cant grow HFS+ partitions: http://gparted.sourceforge.net/features.php

Comment: If it can't grow HFS+, then use it to move the Boot Camp partition, and then Disk Utility to grow HFS+ into the freed space.

Comment: if that worked in the first place, i could use Disk Utility to resize the HFS+ partition anyway, which it wont let me do!